# Cannot delete file from /home by rm command

Tags: command-line, files, delete, rm

I cannot delete a file in my `/home` folder.
Terminal output give me the message:

```
~$ rm /home/goldap/Загрузки/Put Don Kihota (1934) 
   bash: ошибка синтаксиса около неожиданной лексемы '('
```

Roughly translated:

```
~$ rm /home/goldap/Загрузки/Put Don Kihota (1934) 
   bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

Answer (score 10):

As far as I see it, (And google translate tells me) you need to escape ( and ). Like this:

```
~$ rm /home/goldap/Загрузки/Put\ Don\ Kihota\ \(1934\)
```

Another way to accomplish this, would be to put it in single-quotes.

```
~$ rm '/home/goldap/Загрузки/Put Don Kihota (1934)'
```

Comment: In fact it should say `rm /home/goldap/Загрузки/Put\ Don\ Kihota\ \(1934\)`. Usually typing the beginning of the file name and pressing the tab key will do the job for you.

Comment: Whops. My fault. Correcting.

Comment: putting the path into single quotes should do the same thing, shouldn't it? e.g. `rm '/home/goldap/Загрузки/Put Don Kihota (1934)'`

Comment: Single quotes gives the same result, yes.